# JQuery validation character minumum

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but basically this is what I have.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('form#status_form').submit(function(){ 
         var statusV = $('input#status_updated2').val();
         if(statusV.length > 255)
         {
         $('em#statusError').fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
         }
         else
         {
        //do cool stuff

        }
    }); 
});
```

The HTML form that it's pulling from:

```
<em style="display:none;"id="statusError">*NO MORE THAN 255 CHARACTERS</em>
<form id="status_form" name="status_form">
<input type="text" id="status_updated2"  size="57" />
</form>
```

If I enter way more that 255 characters the error message won't come up like it should and the fnctions in the "else" statement go through. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you logged the value of `statusV` to make sure you're getting the value correctly? My first debug option here would be a simple `console.log(statusV, statusV.length)`.

Comment: Do you return false; at the end of submit javascript action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the message is that you're not preventing the default action (form submission) from occurring if there's an error. You can stop this like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('form#status_form').submit(function(event){ 
         var statusV = $('input#status_updated2').val();
         if(statusV.length > 255)
         {
             event.preventDefault(); // stop the form submitting if there's an error.
             $('em#statusError').fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
         }
         else
         {
            //do cool stuff
         }
     }); 
});
```

See the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s59VE/) for a working example.

Comment: YES! This makes sense! I see! I can acceot this answer in 3 minutes! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

How about binding to the `keydown` event and `return`ing `false` if there are already too many characters:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keydown', function (event) {

    //check if the character limit has already been reached, but always allow backspace key strokes and delete key strokes
    if (this.value.length >= 255 && event.which != 8 && event.which != 46) {

        //this will stop the current key stroke from being added to the value of the input
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5yRK2/

`event.which != 8 && event.which != 46` --> this allows the backspace and delete keys to do their thing (since they remove characters instead of add them).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to capture the default form submit event. Try:

```
$('form#status_form').submit(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();    
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is fine. But you might forget to call e.preventDefault() to prevent the #status_form from submitting, which breaks the statusError message.

```
 $('form#status_form').submit(function(e){
    ...
    $('em#statusError').fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
    e.preventDefault();
```